# PHP Fatal Error : Cannot redeclare class Gedmo\Loggable\Loggable

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit

I working to change my symfony application 2.8 to 3.0 and I use `"symfony/phpunit-bridge"                          : "^3.0"` to fix deprecation.

In my code, I use `"stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle"    : "^1.2"` to loggable my doctrine entity like this (I have 2 class that use Loggable) :

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Volvo\ScoreBundle\Tools\PropertyAccessor;

/**
 * Class User
 *
 * @package Volvo\ScoreBundle\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Volvo\ScoreBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @Gedmo\Loggable
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{

const ROLE_ADMIN = 'ROLE_ADMIN';
const ROLE_USER = 'ROLE_USER';

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="bigint")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 */
protected $id = null;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @Gedmo\Versioned
 */
protected $surname = '';

/**
 * @var \DateTime $created
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $createdAt;

/**
 * @var \DateTime $updated
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $updatedAt;

...

}
```

But if I execute test with PHPUnit and phpunit-bridge, I have a PHP fatal error like this :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Gedmo\Loggable\Loggable in /home/vincent/developpement/volvoSf2/vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Loggable/Loggable.php on line 13
```

If you have a solution... Thanks

Comment: maybe search your files for `class Loggable` to determine whats going on

Comment: You'll need to edit your question to indicate what file's being displayed and referencing. Since your error looks unrelated to the code displayed. Typically, the error you're getting comes from namespace collision. You're probably using the keyword "use" to define Loggable shorthand, but you can't declare a class with the namespace Loggable if there's a Loggable alias or the php parser gets confused.

Comment: And better check to see if the loggable extension supports Symfony 3.  Plenty of bundles have yet to be upgraded.